# How to get elements from element in Selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, element

How to select elementS from element. For example I have next element div block and want to select from this div block all elements which have type equals to radio:

```
 private static readonly By divBlock =By.XPath("//*[@contains(@id, 'qst_8220_qst_8235')]");

 private static readonly By elementType = By.XPath(".//*[@type='radio']");
```

This code not working for me:

```
foreach (var elem in WebDriver.FindElement(divBlock).FindElements(elementType))
        {
            elem.Click();
        }
```

> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: *Why* or *how* is it not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Thank you

Comment: Show the line where this error occurs. I think that this "WebDriver" is an instance of your driver. So probably you didn't initialize it.
It must be something like: IWebDriver WebDriver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: everything initialized, error occurs on: `foreach (var elem in WebDriver.FindElement(divBlock).FindElements(elementType))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IWebElement has method findelements. So you can try this way

```
private static readonly By divBlock =By.XPath("//*[@contains(@id, 'qst_8220_qst_8235')]");

private static readonly By elementType = By.XPath(".//*[@type='radio']");

IWebElement Block = Driver.FindElement(divBlock);

List<IWebElement> elementTypes = Block.FindElements(elementType);

Console.WriteLine(elementTypes.count);

foreach (var elem in elementTypes)
{
    elem.Click();
}
```

Comment: I hv edited foreach loop from var to IWebelement. Try that if you are getting error on foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
IWebDriver Driver = new (select some driver);

var divBlock = Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@contains(@id, 'qst_8220_qst_8235')]"));

var elementType = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@type='radio']"));

foreach (var elem in elementType.Count)
{
elem.Click();
}
```

Comment: When you say not working , what exactly is not working ? What error do you get?

Comment: the same error: `error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: You are not even using divBlock later.